# C++ variable in struct from lambda

Tags: c++, time

How to make this compile:

```
struct Features
{
   std::time_t endTime;
   std::time_t startTime =
   {
      std::time_t tmStart  = *gmtime(&startTime);
      tmStart.tm_hour      = 0;
      tmStart.tm_min       = 0;
      tmStart.tm_sec       = 0;
      startTime            = mktime(&tmStart) - _timezone;
   };
};
```

What i like to do, i get current time, and reset 'timed' values, and get only date.

Later i like count from start date to + 7 days ad 'end'.

Comment: See here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80fb82c872ae601e

Comment: Thanks! I was sure that I'm doing something wrong here .. :)

Can you answer question with your code, so i can mark as answered?

Comment: why you need a lambda here? Why not using constructor? like here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fe0b55fc670a2e5. I know immediately invoked lambdas are popular now, but sometimes its more like an abuse of language feature... Or maybe I am too old :-)

Comment: True, stupid me ... there no need to use lambda there, i just converting code from previous version, that was full of #define, and only God knows how that was working.

Answer (score 0):

Final code will be as:
    #include

```
#define SEC_IN_DAY 86400

struct Features
{
   Features()
   {
      std::tm tmStart  = *std::gmtime(&startTime);
      tmStart.tm_hour      = 0;
      tmStart.tm_min       = 0;
      tmStart.tm_sec       = 0;
      int _timezone        = 1;
      startTime   = std::mktime(&tmStart) - _timezone;
      endTime     = startTime + SEC_IN_DAY; // Add +1 days after today day
   }

   std::time_t endTime;
   std::time_t startTime;
};

int main()
{
    Features f;
}
```

Like @marcinj pointed, there was no need to abuse language, and just use simple constructor to init values.

Thanks again for you help :)